# Wordpress - RSS feed provider

Tags: wordpress, rss, content-management-system, feed

We currently have a web site/app and then also use wordpress for our blog.
Wordpress is great and its cms is great.

I have used wordpress in the past to create an RSS feed that we use on the web site.

My question is:

```
Is is possible to use wordpress as a CMS and create a feed from that content that is not publish on the blog/wordpress install?
```

I want to use wordpress's cms, so that i do not have to create my own cms.
However, the content we put in this RSS feed cannot show up on the blog/wordpress site.

Is this possible? I know we are using a plugin to create these RSS feeds. I am not an expert in wordpress, but i believe this is possible.
I also want to use wordpress's category/tags/taxonomy to create feeds based on these values

Once again i want to leverage wordpress's cms to create a hidden feed and publish using RSS. I then want to connect to this feed using different clients.

All data entered into the cms with a certain tag will be hidden/not shown on the blog, but will be available via this RSS feed

Thanks

Comment: you want to create content, create RSS but not publish this content online?

Comment: I want to publish it online, through an rss feed. I do not want the content on the actual blog/wordpress site

Comment: Please see my edit above. I am hoping this makes more sense.

Comment: There are plugins to hide a category from , I believe, and I think every category automatically gets an RSS feed generated for it by WordPress... Do you just want to hide the posts from the main blog page/search, etc?

Comment: Ya. something like a secret feed. I do not want to create my own cms. Wordpress is great in this way. I want to use wordpress/cms to publish a feed, but i do not want the content on the actual blog